# Is there a map() function in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, extjs

ExtJS has Ext.each() function, but is there a map() also hidden somewhere?

I have tried hard, but haven't found anything that could fill this role. It seems to be something simple and trivial, that a JS library so large as Ext clearly must have.

Or when Ext really doesn't include it, what would be the best way to add it to Ext. Sure, I could just write:

```
Ext.map = function(arr, f) { ... };
```

But is this really the correct way to do this?

Comment: What a different behaviour do you want in 'map' which isn't in 'each'?
Wouldn't just Ext.prototype.map = Ext.each.toSource(); help?

Comment: 'each' just applies the function to elements of array, but doesn't return anything. 'map' should in addition return the results of each function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears, that my colleges here are using [ext-basex](http://code.google.com/p/ext-basex/), which extends Array.prototype with map() and other methods.

So I can just write:

```
[1, 2, 3].map( function(){ ... } );
```

Problem solved.

Comment: Over a year later, and Ext still doesn't have map(). Although they have Ext.invoke() and Ext.pluck(), which are just special cases of map(). Anyway... for now we have abandoned ext-basex, which contained too much stuff we didn't need, and written our own little library that adds map() and other useful methods to Array.

Answer (score 4):

As of at least Ext4, Ext.Array.map is included.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.Array-method-map

Answer (score 2):

Since `map` is more of a utility than anything, I don't see why there would be any special way of plugging it into the Ext namespace; the way you propose would work well enough, though you might want to do it thusly:

```
if(Ext && typeof(Ext.map) == "undefined") { // only if Ext exists & map isn't already defined
   Ext.map = function(arr, f) { ... };
}
```

Seems like that would be fine...but then, I don't use ExtJS, so I don't know. I did take a gander at their docs and it doesn't seem like there is anything special to do in this case.

Answer (score 1):

What about using one of the hybrid libraries like Ext+Prototype or Ext+Jquery.  I've been using Extjs+Prototypejs for a while now and it helped me a lot to work into the Extjs code with having the more familiar prototypejs along for the ride as well.

http://extjs.com/products/extjs/build/  will build a custom tar/zip file of all the files you need to run extjs and (prototypejs|jquery|yahooUI).

Comment: As I sayd, I already have my problem solved by using ext-basex, but I'll keep your suggestion in mind.

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS doesn't replace Javascript language itself. Array functions aren't in the focus of ExtJS core. However there is a special Ext.Array object type. You can extend it on your own.

EDIT: Not Ext.Array, but just extended Array object.

Comment: There is no Ext.Array. Ext actually extends the Array.prototype itself with indexOf() and remove() methods.

Comment: Yes, my mismatch in hierarchy. It is just extended Array object. But this even better for your case.